# Rotating a 2d sub-array using numpy without aliasing effects

Tags: numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, rotation, python-2.4

I would like to rotate only the positive value pixels in my 2d array some degree about the center point. The data represents aerosol concentrations from a plume dispersion model, and the chimney position is the origin of rotation.

I would like to rotate this dispersion pattern given the wind direction.

The concentrations are first calculated for a wind direction along the x-axis and then translated to their rotated position using a 2d linear rotation about the center point of my array (the chimney position) for all points whose concentration is > 0. 
The input X,Y to the rotation formula are pixel indexes.

My problem is that the output is aliased since integers become floats. In order to obtain integers, I rounded up or down the output. However, this creates null cells which become increasingly numerous as the angle increases.

Can anyone help me find a solution to my problem? I would like to fix this problem if possible using numpy, or a minimum of packages...

The part of my script that deals with computing the concentrations and rotating the pixel by 50°N is the following. Thank you for your help.

```
def linear2D_rotation(xcoord,ycoord,azimuth_degrees):
    radians = (90 - azimuth_degrees) * (np.pi / 180) # in radians
    xcoord_rotated = (xcoord * np.cos(radians)) - (ycoord * np.sin(radians))
    ycoord_rotated = (xcoord * np.sin(radians)) + (ycoord * np.cos(radians))
    return xcoord_rotated,ycoord_rotated

u_orient = 50 # wind orientation in degres from North
kernel = np.zeros((NpixelY, NpixelX))  # initialize matrix
Yc = int((NpixelY - 1) / 2)  # position of central pixel
Xc = int((NpixelX - 1) / 2)  # position of central pixel

nk = 0
for Y in list(range(0,NpixelX)):
    for X in list(range(0,NpixelY)):
        # compute concentrations only in positive x-direction
        if (X-Xc)>0:
            # nnumber of pixels to origin point (chimney)
            dx = ((X-Xc)+1)
        dy = ((Y-Yc)+1)
        # distance of point to origin (chimney)
        DX = dx*pixel_size_X
        DY = dy*pixel_size_Y
        # compute diffusivity coefficients
        Sy, Sz = calcul_diffusivity_coeff(DX, stability_class)
        # concentration at ground level below the centerline of the plume
        C = (Q / (2 * np.pi * u * Sy * Sz)) * \
            np.exp(-(DY / (2 * Sy)) ** 2) * \
            (np.exp(-((Z - H) / (2 * Sz)) ** 2) + np.exp(-((Z + H) / (2 * Sz)) ** 2))  # at point away from center line
        C = C * 1e9  # convert MBq to Bq

        # rotate only if concentration value at pixel is positive
        if C > 1e-12:
            X_rot, Y_rot = linear2D_rotation(xcoord=dx, ycoord=dy,azimuth_degrees=u_orient)
            X2 = int(round(Xc+X_rot))
            Y2 = int(round(Yc-Y_rot)) # Y increases downwards
            # pixels that fall out of bounds -> ignore
            if (X2 > (NpixelX - 1)) or (X2 < 0) or (Y2 > (NpixelY - 1)):
                continue
            else:
                # replace new pixel position in kernel array
                kernel[Y2, X2] = C
```

The original array to be rotated

[image]

The rotated array by 40°N showing the data loss

[image]

Comment: A different approach is, for each pixel in the rotated image find the neighboring pixels in the original image and operate a weighted mean of their values

Comment: All that is a bit hard to read... do you rotate the entire array, or do you apply different rotations to local regions?

Comment: Can't you be persuaded out of that only positive constraint? It feels rather unsound to me. Why not simply rotate the density map? `scipy.ndimage` has functions for that.

Comment: @kazemakase, where the pixel concentration is positive, I rotate the pixel by the degree. I therefore do not rotate the entire array, to save time.

Comment: My constraint is to keep a square matrix with only the dispersion rotated. Rather than apply image rotation methods for which you end up with the full image rotated.

Comment: What else is there in the image that could be rotated? In any case you could just mask that away. The output shape you can specify. I guarantee you that will be faster than your nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem description is not 100% clear, but here are a few recommendations:

1.) Don't reinvent the wheel. There are standard solutions for things like rotating pixels. Use them! In this case

- `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform` for performing the rotation
- a homogeneous coordinate matrix for specifying the rotation
- nearest neighbor interpolation (parameter `order=0` in code below).

2.) Don't loop where not necessary. The speed you gain by not processing non-positive pixels is nothing against the speed you lose by looping. Compiled functions can ferry around a lot of redundant zeros before hand-written python code catches up with them.

3.) Don't expect a solution that maps pixels one-to-one because it is a fact that there will be points that are no ones nearest neighbor and points that are nearest neighbor to multiple other points. With that in mind, you may want to consider a higher order, smoother interpolation.

Comparing your solution to the standard tools solution we find that the latter

[image]

gives a comparable result much faster and without those hole artifacts.

Code (without plotting). Please note that I had to transpose and `flipud` to align the results :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as sim
from scipy import stats

def mock_data(n, Theta=50, put_neg=True):
    y, x = np.ogrid[-20:20:1j*n, -9:3:1j*n, ]
    raster = stats.norm.pdf(y)*stats.norm.pdf(x)
    if put_neg:
        y, x = np.ogrid[-5:5:1j*n, -3:9:1j*n, ]
        raster -= stats.norm.pdf(y)*stats.norm.pdf(x)
        raster -= (stats.norm.pdf(y)*stats.norm.pdf(x)).T
    return {'C': raster * 1e-9, 'Theta': Theta}

def rotmat(Theta, offset=None):
    theta = np.radians(Theta)
    c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    if offset is None:
        return np.array([[c, -s] [s, c]])
    R = np.array([[c, -s, 0], [s, c,0], [0,0,1]])
    to, fro = np.identity(3), np.identity(3)
    offset = np.asanyarray(offset)
    to[:2, 2] = offset
    fro[:2, 2] = -offset
    return to @ R @ fro

def f_pp(C, Theta):
    m, n = C.shape
    clipped = np.maximum(0, 1e9 * data['C'])
    clipped[:, :n//2] = 0
    M = rotmat(Theta, ((m-1)/2, (n-1)/2))
    return sim.affine_transform(clipped, M, order = 0)

def linear2D_rotation(xcoord,ycoord,azimuth_degrees):
    radians = (90 - azimuth_degrees) * (np.pi / 180) # in radians
    xcoord_rotated = (xcoord * np.cos(radians)) - (ycoord * np.sin(radians))
    ycoord_rotated = (xcoord * np.sin(radians)) + (ycoord * np.cos(radians))
    return xcoord_rotated,ycoord_rotated

def f_OP(C, Theta):
    kernel = np.zeros_like(C)
    m, n = C.shape
    for Y in range(m):
        for X in range(n):
            if X > n//2:
                c = C[Y, X] * 1e9
                if c > 1e-12:
                    dx = X - n//2 + 1
                    dy = Y - m//2 + 1
                    X_rot, Y_rot = linear2D_rotation(xcoord=dx, ycoord=dy,azimuth_degrees=Theta)
                    X2 = int(round(n//2+X_rot))
                    Y2 = int(round(m//2-Y_rot)) # Y increases downwards
                    # pixels that fall out of bounds -> ignore
                    if (X2 > (n - 1)) or (X2 < 0) or (Y2 > (m - 1)):
                        continue
                    else:
                        # replace new pixel position in kernel array
                        kernel[Y2, X2] = c
    return kernel

n = 100
data = mock_data(n, 70)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That helped a lot. I am new to Python and programming.

Comment: This is interesting but sometimes it is necessary to "reinvent the wheel". Sometimes the wheel isnot as perfect and new good versions can appear. I say this because in my case I need to rotate arrays that have more than 2^32 elements and the standard scikit and PIL libraries dont work. So I still have this problem and no solution.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Well, that is a lot of pixels. How many exactly? And what dtype? Does it fit in your rmemory? If yes you could split the target into tiles and do them one by one. That would be relatively easy to do.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Hi. Well I work with microscopy images. They are usually 100k pixels by 100k pixels more or less. and I am working on moving pieces or those images around. Creating a PIL or scikit image creates a lot of overhead. So I simply use the external scikit tifffile (with 3 f) to load all the image. I have the memory, I just dont want to create a lot of useless objects.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I have memory that doesnt mean I want to squander it, also I try to make it as fast as possible. But I just realized that in my case the solution is not to go from the moving space to the reference one, but the other way, I have to calculate the positions on the resulting image and then look for the intensities in the other image. I knew it all along but I had forgotten.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Haha, so you forgot about your own brilliant solution? You must be either a genius or getting long in the tooth ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer haha. I am not a genius and I don't understand what the other thing is. In theory I know things I can do, but implementing of finding good implementations is tricky.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy Ah, so you only got it solved in your head? I think unless you need it blistering fast this kind of problem is just a matter of trial and error, you know, which way do I have to apply the transformation matrix? This offset do I have to add or subtract it? You can try and solve it by logic. Or just try both ways and see which gives the right result.