# Using Scipy.ndimage to Rotate an Array within Np.Nan Values

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, scipy.ndimage

I have an elevation array from a .tif LiDAR surface. Example array below.

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
import numpy as np
test_surface_nan =  [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,   1,    np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                     [np.nan, np.nan,   1,      2,      1,    np.nan, np.nan],
                     [np.nan,   1,      2,      3,      2,      1,    np.nan],
                     [np.nan, np.nan,   1,      2,      1,    np.nan, np.nan],
                     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,   1,    np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]
```

I am attempting to rotate the values within the `test_surface_nan` such that the values begins in `row[1]`using the following code.

```
test_surface_array_nan = np.array(test_surface_nan)
test_surface_array_nan_rotated = rotate(test_surface_array_nan,45,reshape=True)
```

I receive the below array. Why did the elements larger than 0 get turned into np.nan values, the np.nan values get turned into 0?

[image]

this was definitely not what I was expecting when looking at the [scipy.ndimage.rotate website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)

my expectation was something along the lines of the below example

```
maybe_test_surface_nan =  [  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                             [np.nan,    1,   np.nan,   1,    np.nan,    1,   np.nan],
                             [np.nan, np.nan,   2,    np.nan,   2,    np.nan, np.nan],
                             [np.nan,    1,   np.nan,   3,    np.nan,    1,   np.nan],
                             [np.nan, np.nan,   2,    np.nan,   2,    np.nan, np.nan],
                             [np.nan,    1, np.nan,     1,    np.nan,    1,   np.nan],
                             [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]
```

Comment: I think you've a typo in your code: should this ```rotate(test_surface_array,45,reshape=True)``` be ```rotate(test_surface_nan,45,reshape=True)``` instead (different variable name) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `order=` parameter that controls the interpolation. Try to set this parameter to `0`:

```py
test_surface_array_nan_rotated = rotate(
    test_surface_array_nan, 45, reshape=True, order=0
)

print(test_surface_array_nan_rotated)
```

Prints:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. nan  1.  1.  1.  1. nan  0.  0.]
 [ 0. nan nan  1.  2.  2.  1. nan nan  0.]
 [ 0. nan nan  1.  2.  2.  1. nan nan  0.]
 [ 0.  0. nan  1.  1.  1.  1. nan  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: is it normal to lose the 3 in the center of the array when rotating?

Comment: @Patstro I guess it depends on the used algorithm. Maybe the accepted answer in this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693177/rotating-a-2d-sub-array-using-numpy-without-aliasing-effects

Comment: Thank you I will look into it. do you have other recommendations on different approaches that would achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Patstro Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/484627/10035985